# Call Back for belongs_to association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, belongs-to

Like `after_add` callback for `has_and_belongs_to_many` association is there any call back or work around to get after_add functionality for belongs_to association. 
One work around is to use after/before save call backs and dirty object functionality.

```
belongs_to :video
after_save :after_save_task

def after_save_task
 do_stuff if video_id_changed?
end

def do_stuff
 ### do stuff
end
```

But I cannot `save(true)` in do_stuff since its going into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the feature for adding callbacks for has_on and belongs_to is not yet added. see this thread https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/586

One dirty solution for your specific problem would be to add some dirty attribute to suggest if update has already been made.

like this

```
belongs_to :video
after_save :after_save_task
attr_accessor :stuff_done

def after_save_task
 do_stuff if video_id_changed? && !stuff_done
end

def do_stuff
 stuff_done = true
 ### do stuff
 ## Saving record here would be fine.
end
```

Again this is truly a hack, there might exist some better solution for this.

Comment: Thank you, its one of the solution. Another one which I found was to use update_column, which would avoid the call backs.

Answer (score 0):

How about overriding the setter method?
Rails guides has an exam0le of [this here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

an excerpt of which states

> > Overriding generated methods
>
> Association methods are generated in a module that is included into
>   the model class, which allows you to easily override with your own
>   methods and call the original generated method with super. For
>   example:

```
   class Car < ActiveRecord::Base   belongs_to :owner   belongs_to
     :old_owner

     def owner=(new_owner)
         self.old_owner = self.owner
         super
     end
   end
```

> If your model class is Project, the module is named
>   Project::GeneratedAssociationMethods. The GeneratedAssociationMethods
>   module is included in the model class immediately after the
>   (anonymous) generated attributes methods module, meaning an
>   association will override the methods for an attribute with the same
>   name.

I appreciate this is an old question but I stumbled on it looking for a similar solution